# AucTeX/emacs problem with '$' character

Tags: emacs, latex

AucTeX on emacs is pretty amazing tool, but when I write one single '$', all the coloring is broken.

Normally one '$' is accompanied by another '$' to express math equations, but for source listing single '$' is frequently used.

```
\begin{Verbatim}
(let ((buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously
...
    (re-search-forward "^$" nil 'move) <-- It breaks the coloring 
...
\end{Verbatim}
```

The easy solution is as follows to match the '$'.

```
(re-search-forward "^$" nil 'move) ;; $
```

Is there any option in AucTeX to prevent this single '$' problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AUCTeX knows that `$` is not special in verbatim environments, but you have to tell it that `Verbatim` is a verbatim environment by arranging for it to appear in `LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local`.

If AUCTeX is installed optimally, it already knows, because AUCTeX loads a style hook for each file you load through `\usepackage` and friends. You may need to tell it to parse your header file with `C-c C-n` (`TeX-normal-mode`).

If that's not enough, it means `Verbatim` was defined in a style file for which AUCTeX doesn't have enough information. You can tell AUCTeX to parse some or all the style files you have installed; see the “Automatic” chapter in the AUCTeX manual.

Sometimes AUCTeX doesn't manage to parse the style file; then you can do this part by hand. The code below assumes that you're getting the `Verbatim` environment from the `fancyvrb` package; adapt the name otherwise. Create a file called `fancyvrb.el` in one of the directories mentioned in `TeX-style-path` with the following contents (there may be other things worth putting there, I've just adapted `alltt.el`):

```
(TeX-add-style-hook
 "fancyvrb"
 (lambda ()
   (LaTeX-add-environments "BVerbatim" "LVerbatim" "SaveVerbatim" "Verbatim")
   (make-local-variable 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list)
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list '("BVerbatim" current-indentation))
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list '("LVerbatim" current-indentation))
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list '("SaveVerbatim" current-indentation))
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-indent-environment-list '("Verbatim" current-indentation))
   (make-local-variable 'LaTeX-verbatim-regexp)
   (setq LaTeX-verbatim-regexp (concat LaTeX-verbatim-regexp "\\|\\([BL]?\\|Save\\)Verbatim"))
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local "BVerbatim")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local "LVerbatim")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local "SaveVerbatim")
   (add-to-list 'LaTeX-verbatim-environments-local "Verbatim")
   (when (and (featurep 'font-latex)
              (eq TeX-install-font-lock 'font-latex-setup))
     (font-latex-set-syntactic-keywords)
     (setq font-lock-set-defaults nil)
     (font-lock-set-defaults))))
```

(I thought you could also do it manually through file variables, but this turns out not to work, because the font-lock settings are built before the file local variables are initialized, and I don't see a workaround.)

Comment: For the final method, is it just OK to copy them to the last line of TeX source code? It doesn't seem to work in that way.

Comment: @prosseek: sorry, I made a typo in the variable name, now fixed. But even then I just tested and it doesn't work for me. It looks like the variable is set after the coloring parameters are set up, and I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Ok, using a file local variable won't work, so *style*.el is the way to go. I edited my answer to include the code for this.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason to use Verbatim vs. verbatim?  verbatim makes everything in the section the same color for me.  As an aside, I prefer to use the [listings package.](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Listings) for showing program code in latex.

> Using the package listings you can add non-formatted text as you would do with \begin{verbatim} but its main aim is to include the source code of any programming language within your document.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and I see that listing is the better option. But, in terms of emacs/AucTeX, I see the same problem.